# Definition of conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis

In the Conway's book "Functions of One Complex Variable", page 46, the definition of *conformal map* regards the angle preserving property plus the existence of the following limit:

$\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow a} \frac{|f(z)-f(a)|}{|z-a|}$.

What is the meaning of this additional limit property?

Comment: It means $f‘(a)$ exists.

Comment: ok, but in the same line he says "if $f$ is analytic and $f'(z)\neq 0$, then $f$ is conformal". Would not that be redundant?

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_z$ be a curve in the complex z plane and $h = f(z)$ ananalytic function defining a change of variables from $z$ to $h$ the complex variable. Under this transformation the curve  $C_z$ is mapped into a new curve  $C_h$. We now look for geometrical properties of $C_h$ that are indemendent of the shape of $C_z$. The matematical description of $C_z$ can be given by $z(s) = x(s) + i y(s)$, with $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic for $z$ in some domain of the complex $z$-plane denoted by D. The image $h$ of a continuous curve is also continuous. It can be written as $h = u(x(s),y(s)) + i v(x(s),y(s))$ with $u,v \in \mathbb{R}$. Because $x(s)$ and $y(s)$ are continuous functions of $s$, it follows that $u$ and $v$ are also continuous functions of $s$, which establishes the continuity of $h$. The part of $C_z$ that is contained in D is differentiable, and consequently its image is differentiable. In other word, the existance of
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow a} \frac{|f(z)-f(a)|}{|z-a|} 
\end{equation}
guaranttee that $h$ is differentiable, but this is not enough. This is because $f(z)$ can map the part of $C_z$ contained in D into a curve which is self intersecting. In order to avoid this the additional conditions $f'(z_0) \neq 0$ and $z'(s_0) \neq 0$ are required. As a matter of fact, given
\begin{equation}
\frac{z(s)}{ds}=\frac{dx(s)}{ds}+i \frac{dy(s)}{ds}
\end{equation}
with $f(z)$ analytic in a domain containing the open neighborhood of $z_0 =z(s_0)$ we can write
\begin{equation}
\frac{h(s)}{ds}\big|_{s=s_0}=f'(z_0) \frac{dz(s)}{ds}\big|_{s=s_0}
\end{equation}
If $f'(z_0) \neq 0$ and $z'(s_0) \neq 0$ it follows that $h'(s_0)\neq 0$ and $\arg dh = \arg dz + \arg f'(z_0)$. For points where $f'(z_0) \neq 0$ , analytic transformations preserve angles.